# How is $\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{3}+2}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{3}+1)}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How is $\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{3}+2}{4}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{3}+1)}{4}$?
(Prove by using algebraic manipulation not by calculation)

I've tried to come up with something myself but I can't find a solution, I must be missing something.

Comment: Did you try squaring both sides?

Comment: **Hint:** instead of proving directly that they are equal, try proving an equivalent equality. Start by squaring both sides.

Comment: At some point or other, you must use $(\sqrt{3}+1)^2 = 2(\sqrt{3}+2)$ or something similar, I think. If that counts as calculation, then I don't see how. If it counts as algebraic manipulation, you're home.

Comment: $2(\sqrt{3}+1)^2/16=(8+4\sqrt{3})/16$, so expand the first root's radicand by $4$.

Comment: I am know sure to know what is the difference between calculation and algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, note that $$\frac{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{3}+1)}4$$ is positive, and that $$\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{3}+1)}4\right)^2=\frac{2(\sqrt3+1)^2}{16}=\frac{2\sqrt3+4}8=\frac{\sqrt3+2}4,$$ so we're done.

Answer (score 2):

There is a more general trick: if you want to find $\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+2}$ then write
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+2}=x+y\sqrt{3}$$
with rational $x,y$ and square this equation:
$$\sqrt{3}+2=x^2+3y^2+2xy\sqrt{3}.$$
Since we suppose that $x$ and $y$ are rational we get
$$x^2+3y^2=2,$$
$$2xy=1.$$
From here $t^2-4t+3=0$ for $t=\frac{x}{y}$ etc.

Comment: How did you get 2xy = 1? I think your approach is interesting but I don't understand.

Comment: I will add this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{3}+2}{4}} &= \frac{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{3}+1)}{4}\\
{\frac{\sqrt{3}+2}{4}} &= \frac{{2}(\sqrt{3}+1)^2}{16}\\
{\frac{\sqrt{3}+2}{4}} &= \frac{4+2\sqrt{3}}{8}\\
{\frac{\sqrt{3}+2}{4}} &= \frac{\sqrt{3} + 2}{4}\tag*{$\blacksquare$}\end{align}$$

Comment: This kind of thing can also "prove" $-1=1$

Comment: @mercio: Not if one observes that $\frac{\sqrt2(\sqrt3+1)}4$ is nonnegative.