# How to show that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

> $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{2}$

How to change $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ into  $\dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: Hard to interpret, for writing $\frac{a}{b}$ give use \frac{a}{b}.

Comment: I am still editing it...

Comment: A possible [duplicate target](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/540233/11619). Also, Bill Dubuque has posted a script for denesting nested square roots. I'm afraid I couldn't find it now, but please search. Preferrably before posting (applies to answerers with more force as they often have more experience with how the site is supposed to work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ (\sqrt u + \sqrt v)^2 = u+v + 2\sqrt{u\,v }$

So at first bring in $2$ in front of the radical sign.

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\sqrt{\frac{4+2\sqrt3}{2}}$$

Next find two factors for $3$ whose sum is $4$

They are easy to guess. They are $3$ and $1$;

(... or else you need to solve another quadratic equation)

$$ \sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt3 +1)^2}{2}}=\sqrt{  \frac{2(\sqrt3 +1)^2}{4}} $$

where the denominator is made to be $4$ so that while square rooting, $2$ would stay there.

Next manipulate numerator to make them  squares of two terms and make denominator also a square

$$\sqrt{  \frac{(\sqrt{2})^2(\sqrt3 +1)^2}{2^2}} $$

that  is now ( cancelling out squares and square roots) and multiplying two terms in the numerator:

$$ \dfrac{\sqrt 6 +\sqrt 2}{2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

---

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\sqrt{\frac{4+2\sqrt3}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{(1+\sqrt3)^2}{2}}=\frac{1+\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i am looking for the concept that i forgot, that is by what Narasimham said.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the identity
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you. It is good. Kinda complicated, but. What's the name of this identity?

Comment: I don't think it has one. To show it's true, under correct assumptions, simply square both sides to get equality.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\left( \frac{\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{6 + 2 \sqrt{6} \sqrt{2} + 2}{4} = ?$$

Comment: ... plus both numbers are positive

Answer (score 1):

Assume $$\sqrt{a+\sqrt b}=\sqrt c+\sqrt d$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are all rational.

Then

$$a+\sqrt b=c+2\sqrt{cd}+d.$$

By identification

$$\begin{cases}a=c+d,\\b=4cd.\end{cases}$$

From this,

$$4c^2+4cd-4ac=4c^2-4ac+b=0.$$

This is a quadratic equation in $c$, with roots

$$c=\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b}}2.$$

So for a rational solution to exist, $a^2-b$ must be a perfect rational square.

---

With $a=2,b=3$,

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\sqrt{\frac12}+\sqrt{\frac32}=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt6}2.$$

Comment: Thank you. But i am confused after "From this" to the rest

Comment: @Lifeforbetter: $4c\,a=4c\,c+4c\,d$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change $\sqrt{2+ \sqrt{3}}$ into $\dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{2}$, then go through the following calculation steps from bottom to top. If you want to change $\dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{2}$ into $\sqrt{2+ \sqrt{3}}$, then go through the following calculation steps from top to bottom. Either way we get equality $\sqrt{2+ \sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

\begin{align*} 
\dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{2} &= \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2} 
&& a = \sqrt{a^2} \text{ for } a \geq 0
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{(\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2})^2}{2^2}} 
&& \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^2 = \dfrac{a^2}{b^2}
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{(\sqrt{6})^2+2\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{6}+(\sqrt{2})^2}{4}}
&& (a+b)^2 = a^2+2\cdot a\cdot b+b^2
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{6+2\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{6}+2}{4}} 
&& a = (\sqrt{a}) \text{ for } a \geq 0
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{6+\sqrt{4}\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{6}+2}{4}} 
&& 2 = \sqrt{4}
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{6+\sqrt{4\cdot 2\cdot 6}+2}{4}} 
&&   \sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{b}\cdot \sqrt{c} = \sqrt{a\cdot b\cdot c}
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{6+\sqrt{48}+2}{4}} 
&&  4\cdot 2\cdot 6=8\cdot6=48
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{6+\sqrt{3\cdot 16}+2}{4}} 
&&  48 = 3 \cdot 16
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{6+\sqrt{3}\cdot \sqrt{16}+2}{4}} 
&&    \sqrt{a\cdot b} = \sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{b} 
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{6+\sqrt{3}\cdot 4+2}{4}} 
&&    \sqrt{16} = \sqrt{4^2} = 4
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{6+4 \cdot \sqrt{3}+2}{4}} 
&&   a \cdot b = b\cdot a
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{8+4 \cdot \sqrt{3}}{4}} 
&&   6+2=8
\\&= \sqrt{\dfrac{8}{4}+\dfrac{4 \cdot \sqrt{3}}{4}} 
&&   \dfrac{a+b}{c}=\dfrac{a}{c}+\dfrac{b}{c}
\\&= \sqrt{2+ \sqrt{3}} 
\end{align*}